# Angular Datatables: Unknown provider

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatable, angular-datatables

I'm new to JS and Angular trying to implement the angular-datatable version in my project.

First I used the "angular-way", which turned out to be a bad decision based on performance. I have a lot of rows in my table. So I've decided to try building my datatable with ajax and building my columns with dtOptionsBuilder and filling the table using dtOptions.

However, I'm having some complications... I get an unkown provider error.. More specifically:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: datatablesProvider <-
>   datatables <- OverviewCtrl

I'm not quite sure, what I'm doing wrong? Here's my controller.

```
angular.module("invoices").controller("OverviewCtrl", ["apiService", "datatables", 'utilsService', "$q", "invoiceService", "ngDialog", "$controller", "authFactory", "redirectService", "$rootScope", OverviewCtrl]);

function OverviewCtrl(apiService, utilsService, dtOptionsBuilder, dtColumnBuilder, $q, invoiceService, ngDialog, $controller, authFactory, redirectService, $rootScope) {
var NUMBER_OF_TIMEENTRIES_TO_SHOW = 10;
var vm = this;

if (!authFactory.identity.isAuthenticated) {
    redirectService.redirect("overview", 2, "login", 3);
}

vm.dtOptions = dtOptionsBuilder.fromSource(vm.latestInvoices)
.withPaginationType('full_numbers');
vm.dtColumns = [
    dtColumnBuilder.newColumn('CompanyName').withTitle('Client'),
    dtColumnBuilder.newColumn('ProjectName').withTitle('Project'),
    dtColumnBuilder.newColumn('InvoiceID').withTitle('ID'),
    dtColumnBuilder.newColumn('InvoiceDate').withTitle('Inv. Date'),
    dtColumnBuilder.newColumn('InvoiceStart').withTitle('Start Date'),
    dtColumnBuilder.newColumn('InvoiceEnd').withTitle('End Date'),
    dtColumnBuilder.newColumn('DKKexVAT').withTitle('DKK ex VAT'),
    dtColumnBuilder.newColumn('CustomerInvoiceGroup.Label').withTitle('CIG'),
    dtColumnBuilder.newColumn('Attention').withTitle('Attention'),
    dtColumnBuilder.newColumn('CustManager').withTitle('Customer Manager'),
    dtColumnBuilder.newColumn('Regarding').withTitle('Regarding'),
    dtColumnBuilder.newColumn('DueDate').withTitle('Due Date'),
    dtColumnBuilder.newColumn('Finalized').withTitle('Finalized'),
    dtColumnBuilder.newColumn('Paid').withTitle('Paid')
];
```

I've injected datatables into my app.module.js as listed in the manual.

```
'use strict';
(function() {
    angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'invoices', 'ngDialog', 'infinite-scroll', 'datatables']);
})();
```

Comment: It is dependency injection error. You need to include 'datatables' js librabry.

Comment: Is it referenced in the index.html? As in is the package included?

Comment: I've loaded the required libraries according to the manual.

<script src="/bower_components/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

    <script src="/bower_components/datatables/media/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>

    <script src="/bower_components/angular-datatables/dist/angular-datatables.min.js"></script>`

Comment: you have `injected` dependacy in both `controller` and `module`. Only inject in modules.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the example in thier [site](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/withOptions):

You only need to inject `datatables` to the module.

Remove the dependency from the controller.

Comment: That did it! Thanks! :)

Comment: Sure, see more example at http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/gettingStarted